# Use springboot 3.2.1(spring 6.1.2) , when didn't use `spring-boot-starter-parent` in maven, `@RequestParam` is Required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I used `springboot3.2.1` and `maven3.9.0` to create project, But i didn't used `spring-boot-starter-parent`, Instead use `spring-boot-dependencies` , I just want to manager my dependency, when i request a simple api, my server throw exception:

`Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.`.

- api request url :  `http://localhost:8080/user/hello?name=ddd`
- Error Java code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(String name) {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
}
```

- Error maven `pom.xml` :

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now I and my friend find two way to fix it.

1. add `@RequestParam("name")` to `String name` before, like:

```java
        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
            return "hello " + name;
        }
```

2. use `spring-boot-starter-parent`, like:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

I don't know if this is the Spring official expected result? Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Spring, then you should use tools that you have provided to help Spring to interpret your requests, you can use @RequestParam or @PathVariable, but using a method with just `String name`  is simply not a way to go.

> By default, method parameters that use this annotation are required

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/requestparam.html

You can set for that parameter to be optional, but @RequestParam still needs to be there like

```
(@RequestParam(required = false) String name)
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

If you do not want to use @RequestParam you can make use of @PathVariable annotation

@RequestParam extracts values from the query of string

@PathVariable extracts values from the URI path

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Here is a pieces from a REST controller and if you pay attention, none of the method arguments are without annotation before them.

```
@DeleteMapping("/employees/{employeeId}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int employeeId) {

@PatchMapping("/employees/{id}/{firstName}")
    public String patchEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id, @PathVariable String firstName) {

@PutMapping("/employees")
    public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee theEmployee) {

@PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee theEmployee) {

@GetMapping("/employees/{employeeId}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable int employeeId) {
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know you said. I just noticed in `https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/requestparam.html` last sentence is: `Note that use of @RequestParam is optional (for example, to set its attributes). By default, any argument that is a simple value type (as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty) and is not resolved by any other argument resolver, is treated as if it were annotated with @RequestParam.`  
This makes me think that i should be able to receive String parameters without @RequestParam, so I raised this question.

Comment: By the way, I often omit `@RequestParam` in older versions of spring, even if i don't use `spring-boot-starter-parent`.